# Formatting of SQL in code

Tags: python, sql

I have the following in my python code, which I think looks pretty ugly, and I would like to be able to improve if possible.

```
self.cursor.execute('''INSERT IGNORE INTO main_tvseriesinstance 
                       (apple_id, name, provider_id, itunes_url, metadata_language_id, video_source_language_id, original_spoken_language_id) 
                       VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)''',
                       (artist_apple_id, name, provider_id, view_url, metadata_language, video_source_language, original_spoken_language))
```

How could I improve this statement in the codebase?

Comment: I think it looks 'fine'.

Comment: Looks fine.  You could wrap before the first triple-quote if you prefer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a stored procedure and then you don't have to see all the SQL text.  That's about your only chance because SQL is a verbose language and insert and update statements are ugly by general coding standards.  Line breaks helps.

Select statements can be beautiful, though.

Comment: Could you please show an example of how it'd look with a stored procedure?

Comment: I would just be searching for it.  Never used python, so I unfamiliar with the syntax.  But unless you have DB control and want to change field names your insert statement isn't going to be any prettier in any programming language.